Is there any way to remove all the favorites from the treebar in heidisql?
I am constantly having to deal with a group of tables at a time in a database with too many tables, I would like to know if there is any easy way to untag all the favorite tables at once in Heidisql.

Normally you should just unpress the favorites button to see all tables - the button right besides the table filter box:

If you want to remove the favorite indicator permanently, you can't do that from multiple objects with one click. You need to click the star icons one by one.
A perhaps better way to manage different filters is to use the two filter boxes. These boxes have a dropdown menu with the last filters you entered, so you can easily switch between them. Also, these filters support regular expressions, for example ^product.*, or (product|custom|properties).
